# SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression, this is unexpected error?

Tags: python-3.x

Why is the error I can't understand i.e. (SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression)

```
for dataset in train_test_data:
    datset['Title'] = dataset['Name'].str.extract(' ([A-Za-z]+)\.'.expand=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have typo in:

```
.extract(' ([A-Za-z]+)\.'.expand=False)
```

it should be:

```
.extract(' ([A-Za-z]+)\.', expand=False)
```